# How to compile a java file from java program in Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I'm getting the error

`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

while compiling a java file programmatically via java program on Heroku.
It's working fine on ec2 and windows.
I'm executing `javac TestClass` through java ProcessBuilder.
Does anyone know why I'm getting this error on Heroku and the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. This is a message from the JVM letting you know that it's using the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable, which Heroku sets automatically based on the dyno size.